# upload same file with different name each time in Load Runner

Tags: file-upload, jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner

I need to upload an excel file in load runner HTTP/HTML script with unique filename each time. The file must present in the directory. Copying files and renaming them will be more manual task. Can anyone tell me is there any automated way to do this? or Load Runnner itself can perform such tasks? Thank you.

Comment: There are probably dozens of ways to accomplish this task.  Can you walk us through the items you have worked to implement so far and their levels of success?

Comment: I tried to use system(command) function with the below code. For some reason, it is not working... char command[100];
 sprintf(command, “copy C:\\source_dir\\srcFile.txt C:\\source_dir\\srcFile-%s.txt”,              
 lr_eval_string (”{iteration_number}”));
 system(command);

Answer (score 0):

1. On each of your load generators make sure that you have a ram drive for the file i/o for the new files.  You are going to have ten, perhaps hundreds or thousands on your load generator.  You do not want contention for the read/write heads of a physical hard drive acting as a drag anchor on the performance of your entire load generator.   It is for this same reason that logging is minimized during test execution.
2. Include the base file as part of your virtual user
3. Use appropriate language API for making a copy of the file from the virtual user directory to the ramdrive on your virtual user generator with a new name.  It might recommend a name which includes virtual user number and iteration number at the end to ensure uniqueness across your virtual user population.
4. Upload your file from the ramdrive as the source
5. Delete your newly created file to return to the same initial condition as the beginning of the iteration.

As you will be engaging a large amount of file i/o for the virtual users it is highly recommended that you monitor the load generators just as you would monitor your application under test. If you are new to LoadRunner and performance testing then this is an excellent opportunity for your mentor/trainer to guide you on a monitoring strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the upload is done using a html form..

Use web_submit_data() with the **FilePath** argument.

but first lets create some parameters to get a real unique filename (very importent)

- create a parameter VUSERID which outputs the current vuser id.
  [image: vuser_id param]
- get/save the current timestamp
  web_save_timestamp_param("TIMESTAMP", LAST);

and here is the request:

```
web_submit_data("i1",
        "Action=https://{LR_SERVER}/{LR_JUNCTION}/upload",
        "Method=POST",
        "EncType=multipart/form-data",
        "Snapshot=t1.inf",
        "Mode=HTML",
        ITEMDATA,
        "Name=FIELDNAME", "Value={VUSERID}{TIMESTAMP}_LOADTEST.xlsx", "File=yes", "FilePath=REALFILEPATH.xlsx", "ContentType=WHATEVERCONTENTTYPE", ENDITEM,
        LAST);
```

The Value={VUSERID}{TIMESTAMP}_LOADTEST.xlsx will be the new (unique) filename. (It is unique for each user and iteration! very importent)
The FilePath points to the real file and its content will be uploaded.